# Should a HDMI cable go to the receiver first or directly to the TV?

Tags: tv, wiring, stereo

I have a receiver for my stereo system and a TV. I am wondering how I should hook these up. Right now I currently have everything (DVD player, Xbox, TV box) all going to the receiver and then one cable going from the receiver to the TV.

I am wondering if this is the proper setup though, and if it should be the other way around. Everything connecting to the TV, and then one wire to the receiver?

Both support various input selections, so it is merely a matter of which way is the proper way if any.

Comment: It really comes down to one thing -- would you prefer to use the TV or the receiver to select which input to watch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it either way. I would connect everything to the receiver and connect a single HDMI cable to the TV.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen it done both ways.  But generally, all devices should go to the receiver with a single cable going to the TV.

Alternatively, you can connect all devices to the TV, with a single audio cable going to the receiver.

Either method should work, and the only real difference is which device (TV or Receiver) you are switching inputs on.